# JPA: Remove orphans within uni-directional one-to-one relationships

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Having devices entities and a separate 'tracker' table. A device might have zero or no trackers, but the device is referenced from tracker. I.e. a tracker for the device might exist or not:

```
public class Tracker {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="OBJID")
    private Device device;

    private int cnt = 0;

    public Tracker() {}

    public Tracker(Device device) {
        this.device = device;
}
```

As you can see, my primary is the same as the device entities id.
Now it is unidirectional, i.e. I don't have a reference from device to tracker.

Is there any way to make sure that if a device will be removed, all trackers referencing  the device will also be removed?

Or is this a wrong approach?